# Strange results when using Gaussian Elimination on systems that have an infinite number of solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am learning Gaussian Elimination in linear algebra class and just worked through the problems at the end of the chapter. For each elimination problem with systems that have infinite solutions, I ended up with an answer that was wrong but sort of correct. For each problem, I arrived at my answer by a sequence of steps that hinged on reducing one of the equations to $ax_i = 0$ and then solving the other two equations from which the $x_i$ term had just been eliminated.

For example

$$
\begin{matrix}  
2x +y +4z = 4 \\
4x +0 +2z = 10\\
-2x +3y -13z = -8\\
\end{matrix}
$$

$$
\begin{matrix}  
2x +y +4z = 4\\
4x +0 +2z = 10\\
0 +4y -9z = -4\\
\end{matrix}
$$

$$
\begin{matrix}  
2x +y +4z = 4\\
0 -2y -6z = 2\\
0 +4y -9z = -4\\
\end{matrix}
$$

$$
\begin{matrix}  
2x +y +4z = 4\\
0 -2y -6z = 2\\
0 +0 -21z = 0\\
\end{matrix}
$$

$$
\begin{matrix}  
2x -1 = 4\\
y = -1\\
z = 0\\
\end{matrix}
$$

$$x =5/2,  y =-1, z=0$$

The correct answer is

$$
x = 5/2 - t/2, y = 4t -1, z=t$$
which would have occurred in my attempt had I found that $x=t$. This same error comes up every time I do these problems, so it occurs to me that, whenever I find $x_i = 0$, maybe I can just change that to $x_i = t$ and then obtain the correct answer.

So, where am I going wrong and why am I getting close to the correct answer in spite of that. Also, could I really just modify this method and reliably get the correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have copied the problem correctly, your answer is correct. Try substituting in the so-called correct answer and see if it really works.

Comment: AGh! you're right. But the others weren't mis-copied, so I still have to figure out where I went wrong with them. thanks.